# Add allure report to massive existing project

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, reporting, allure

We decided to add Allure report to our Java Test Suites.
Unfortunately, the test suites are quite massive which are containing massive amount of tests and steps, therefore we are not able to add the relevant annotations one by one.

Is there any other way to generate the required JSON for the report or any other way to get every method invoked ( like @Step does) to build it myself?

**Additional info**:
We are using Selenium4 and JUnit5.

I am basically looking for a way to create test report containing steps and screenshots or to create the JSON needed for the Allure report without the need to add annotations one by one.